# how to make block design matrix from a long matrix efficiently in R for mixed model?

Tags: r, matrix, mixed-models

When fitting a unbalanced longitudinal data with mixed model: **y = X α + Z a + ξ**, we usually organize the design matrix Z like ablock matrix. Take `n = 3`,  `q = 2` for example,

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1   10    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    2   11    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    3   12    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    4   13    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    5   14    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    6   15
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    7   16
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    8   17
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    9   18
```

However, if have

```
   [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2   11
 [3,]    3   12
 [4,]    4   13
 [5,]    5   14
 [6,]    6   15
 [7,]    7   16
 [8,]    8   17
 [9,]    9   18
```

at hand, **how could we transfer a long format matrix to block matrix efficiently in r besides `for` loops?** I recently tried this way,

```
> library("magic")
> (Zmat <- matrix(1:18, nrow=9))
   [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2   11
 [3,]    3   12
 [4,]    4   13
 [5,]    5   14
 [6,]    6   15
 [7,]    7   16
 [8,]    8   17
 [9,]    9   18

 > row_cuts <- c(2,3,4)
 > cut_num <- length(row_cuts)
 > cut_up <- cumsum(row_cuts)
 > cut_lo <- cut_up - row_cuts +1
 > (Reduce("adiag", mapply(function(i) Zmat[(cut_lo[i]):(cut_up[i]), ], 1:cut_num, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1   10    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    2   11    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    3   12    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    4   13    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    5   14    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    6   15
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    7   16
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    8   17
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    9   18
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have a look a t`bdiag` from the `Matrix` package